# Extracting values from xml file using xpath with multiple conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dev>
 <word string="test1" occurrences="39">
  <systems>
   <system name="paraview">
    <pos file="" part="noun" line="0" occ="39"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="Format" occurrences="39">
  <systems>
   <system name="paraview">
    <pos file="" part="verb" line="0" occ="40"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="Source" occurrences="16">
  <systems>
   <system name="paraview">
    <pos file="" part="verb" line="0" occ="16"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="p4" occurrences="1">
  <systems>
   <system name="Pstoedit">
    <pos file="" part="pronoun" line="0" occ="1"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
 <word string="test1" occurrences="3">
  <systems>
   <system name="Pstoedit">
    <pos file="" part="noun" line="0" occ="3"/>
   </system>
  </systems>
 </word>
</dev>
```

I am trying to extract these two systems [paraview & Pstoedit] that specify the following condition which is both of the systems should have the same exact string.
so the output should give me the number of matching here and say yes there are **two** systems with the condition that you want and the matching string is test1

I tried different commands using xmllint and the final command I think it is the nearest is:

```
xmllint --xpath '//word/systems/system[@name="Pstoedit"][@name="paraview"]/pos[@part="noun"]' file.xml
```

How can I use two conditions for comparison in xpath? please advise.

Updates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="paraview" match="system[@name='paraview']" use="ancestor::word/@string" />

<xsl:template match="/dev">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Number of matched words</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                 <th>Total</th>   
                 <th>Words</th>
                </tr>
    <xsl:variable name="pairs" select="word/systems/system[@name='Pstoedit'][key('paraview', ancestor::word/@string)]" />
    <result>
        <tr>
        <count-pairs>          
           <td> <xsl:value-of select="count($pairs)"/> </td>
        </count-pairs>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <match-strings>
           <td> <xsl:for-each select="$pairs"> </td>
                 <string>
            <td>   <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::word/@string"/> </td>
                </string>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </match-strings>
    </result>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here is the result that I get:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJUBS.png)
I need them to be arranged in a table based on the previous xls and html code like:

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qovne.png)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256081%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to extract these two systems [paraview & Pstoedit] that
>   specify the following condition which is both of the systems should
>   have the same exact string.

You can select all `Pstoedit` systems (or rather their ancestor `word`s) that have a matching `paraview` system by:

```
/dev/word[systems/system/@name='Pstoedit'][@string=/dev/word[systems/system/@name='paraview']/@string]
```

---

> the output should give me the number of matching here and say yes
>   there are **two** systems with the condition that you want ...

Well, each selected node represents a *pair*, so:

```
2 * count ( $theabovexpression )
```

would give you the total number of the nodes involved.

---

> ... and the matching string is test1

I don't think there's a way to do this in XPath alone. Keep in mind that there could be more than one pair, and the matching string could be different for each. However, in XSLT you could do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="paraview" match="system[@name='paraview']" use="ancestor::word/@string" />

<xsl:template match="/dev">
    <xsl:variable name="pairs" select="word/systems/system[@name='Pstoedit'][key('paraview', ancestor::word/@string)]" />
    <result>
        <count-pairs>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($pairs)"/>
        </count-pairs>
        <match-strings>
            <xsl:for-each select="$pairs">
                <string>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::word/@string"/>
                </string>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </match-strings>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <count-pairs>1</count-pairs>
  <match-strings>
    <string>test1</string>
  </match-strings>
</result>
```

---

### Edit:

> I just want the list of strings and the overall count in a table of
>   two columns

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="paraview" match="system[@name='paraview']" use="ancestor::word/@string" />

<xsl:template match="/dev">
    <xsl:variable name="pairs" select="word/systems/system[@name='Pstoedit'][key('paraview', ancestor::word/@string)]" />
    <xsl:variable name="count-pairs" select="count($pairs)" />
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Strings</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$pairs">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::word/@string"/></td>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <td rowspan="{$count-pairs}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$count-pairs"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:if>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return (for example, when two matching pairs are found):

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Strings</th>
      <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>stringone</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>stringtwo</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which your browser should render as:

[image]

Comment: I have tried the commands, but nothing came up with me. So, I am now trying XSLT though I am new to it. I need to know in which extension I should save the xslt file?

Comment: I figured it out. it should be .xsl
So I will be having two files one is xml and another is xls

Comment: I am trying to put the result into a table., but I am not sure about using the <td> and <tr> with xslt. 
I just updated my post.

Comment: @Developer Please post the expected HTML result.

Comment: @Developer That picture is not helpful; please post the expected HTML **code**. --- Note: there's not much here for a table: all you you have is a list of strings and the overall count.

Comment: Yes I already added the html code inside the xslt in the post. Is it what you mean?

Comment: No. I want to understand what you want to get in the end.

Comment: Yes I totally know that, i am gonna do more testing on other systems. So they all should be in a table.

Comment: I just want the list of strings and the overall count in a table of two columns

Comment: my HTML editions did not work fine, it gave me a blank page meaning there is a mistake in the html editings

Comment: @Developer I am afraid none of that makes a lot of sense. I have edited my answer to show how to produce a simple table. If you need something else, then you will have to be much more clearer explaining what it is.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but one I tried the code it did not give my the table. it just gave me a string of words together and next to each other. I think there is a problem with specifying the type of the file.

Comment: Still did not show the table with the same as your code. Could be the browser?

Comment: @Developer What are you using to run the transformation?

Comment: I have two files. One called file.xml and another called file.xsl 
In file.xsl I included "
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> "
and I am using sublime editor and Safari browser.

Comment: I tried to run the code here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/xslt_template.htm and it works fine and the table came in the output.

Comment: @Developer In order to run the transformation in a browser, you must link the XML to the XSLT stylesheet. But this is not related to your question and should not be discussed here.

Comment: I did this already using <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file.xsl"?> in my xml

Comment: Hello again, I have tried the xpath command at the beginning of this post and the results is an empty set, does that command gives the exact matchings strings between the systems?

Comment: Is there a way in xslt that allows me to check whether there are two identical words or not  in an xml file and if yes return that word?

Comment: @Developer I believe it would be better to start a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this XPath?

```
"//word/systems/system[@name='Pstoedit']/pos[@part='noun']|//word/systems/system[@name='paraview']/pos[@part='noun']"
```

This will give you either Pstoedit or paraview system having part = noun

Comment: I have tried this xpath but it do not give me the string name.